# How to set up OpenServer to use magento ee multistore feature?

Tags: multistore, wamp, localhost

I'm working on project which involve magento multistore. I know how it works inside magento, but have no clue how to set up Open Server for this.
Any guesses?
**Add on:**
I have two stores on one magento. They use their own url's.
I had an idea, what aliases could help, but they don't.
In my understanding, each url should change server variables: MAGE_RUN_CODE and MAGE_RUN_TYPE. Well, at least MAGE_RUN_CODE. I can freely edit index.php, if this help, it's not a part of repository.
I could edit an apache ini config of Open Server, but Open Server is overwrites any changes in this files at each server run. Maybe htaccess can help, but I don't know if I can input $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] variable in it.
This is there I stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've managed to do it.
First, in my solution, I have to switch in Open Server Apache module to 2.4 version, and PHP module to 5.5 version, since it was a must.
Second, I've added this lines to htaccess:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'tpw.dev'">
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE chlp_website
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE website
</If>
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'pilgrim.tpw.dev'">
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE pilgrimp_website
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE website
</If>
```

And to link pilgrim.tpw.dev to directory with code, I've added it in the Open Server Parametres window, tab Domains.
This was really that simple.
Soon after I've found, what I could use *SetEnvIf* in htaccess instead of *If* (they are pretty same, but *SetEnvIf* can be used in Apache 2.2), or check domain name in *index.php* file (if you need to emulate nGinx setup, or when htaccess isn't working) with the same result.
Since my work is not sensetive to versions of the modules, I left my first approach to handle.